# Swap with a consecutive line on a pattern match in unix

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk, swap

Can any one help me in sorting this out in sed/awk/perl

Input file

```
Start variable 1
End   variable 2
A
Z
Next 

Start variable b
End   variable a 
X
Y
Next 
...
...
...

Start variable m
End   variable n
M
N
Next
```

If a pattern match  `End` found, swap with its consecutive line

Output file :

```
Start variable 1
A
End variable 2 
Z
Next

Start variable b
X
End variable a
Y
Next
...
...
...

Start variable m
M
End variable n
N
Next
```

Comment: How is the behaviour of two consecutive lines with `End` defined? Would  `A`-`End`-`End` yield `End`-`End`-`A` or `End`-`A`-`End`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Perl solution. `$n` stands for "now", `$b` for "before", i.e. "the previous line was End".

```
perl -ne 'print unless $n = /^End$/; print "End\n" if $b; $b = $n'
```

For the updated version of your question, just add `$l` to remember the line to be printed:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $n = /^End /; $l = $_ if $n ; print $l if $b; $b = $n'
```

Or, equivalen but shorter:

```
perl -ne '$n = /^End / and $l = $_ or print; $b and print $l; $b = $n'
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please check my question again, that END is not a fixed string

Comment: Really i am trying hard to understand that, lets say if we read our input file into array, how to arrange the contents of array in the output file format with the help of that one liner code.. Can me please help in doing this

Comment: @user1228191: Just drop the `-n` option and wrap the code into `for (@array) { ... }`.

Comment: Works Great :) Thanks lot , this is what i tried  `for (@array) { push @new_array, $_ unless $n = /^END/; $l = $_ if $n ; push @new_array, $l if $b; $b = $n };`

Answer (score 3):

`sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/^End\s/{h;n;p;g};p' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n '/^End/{h;n;G};p' inputfile
```

this would do +